# How to open a link in the background ...?

Tags: iframe, redirect

I need to open in the background of my page ( something like a iframe) a webpage that redirects to another webpage.

So A is my main page and I want to open page B, that redirects to page C. So the page B and page C should be opened in the background, without user knowing.

If I use iframe, my current page(A) gets redirected too to C and I don't want this to happen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B redirects to C with a simple `Location: ...` header, your solution should work fine.

If B redirects to C with a script such as `top.location = ...` theres not much you can do about it, sorry.

It's also possible that C contains a "frame buster" which breaks out of iframes.

In other words, you're out of luck unless you go for a very complex solution such as [this frame buster buster](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/preventing-frame-busting-and-click-jacking-ui-redressing/).